# Should use the same Java keystore for SSL and HTTPS communication?

Tags: java, ssl, https, activemq-classic, apache-zookeeper

**A bit of context**

I have 3 instances running `Zookeeper` and `ActiveMQ`.
I want to make my communication secure, so I have to worry about 3 things:

- How follower and the leader communicates (Zookeeper's quorum)
- How ActiveMQ consumers communicates with it (applications/SSL)
- How my team access ActiveMQ WebConsole (https)

Okay, the 1st case [is not possible according to Zookeeper documentation.](http://Quorum%20There%20is%20currently%20no%20support%20for%20SSL%20for%20the%20communication%20between%20ZooKeeper%20servers.)

On my 2nd case; I have created it my own CA certificate, also my own certificates and keystores. That's how I'm using them on **/etc/activemq/conf/activemq.xml**:

```
...
    <persistenceAdapter>

        <replicatedLevelDB
            directory="${activemq.data}/leveldb"
            replicas="3"
            bind="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616"
            zkAddress="activemq1.company.com:2881,activemq2.company.com:2881,activemq3.company.com:2881"
            zkPassword="password"
            zkPath="/activemq/leveldb-stores"
            hostname="activemq3.company.com"
        />


    </persistenceAdapter>
    <sslContext>
        <sslContext keyStore="/usr/share/ca-certificates/company/activemq/keystore" keyStorePassword="password-2" trustStore="/usr/share/ca-certificates/company/activemq/trustore" trustStorePassword="password-2" />
    </sslContext>
...
```

And finally, my 3rd case; in order to have a valid certificate authority, I'm using [Let'sEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) api to generate my new valid certificates and with them, I create a new keystore; which is used like this:

```
...
<!--
    Enable this connector if you wish to use https with web console
-->
<bean id="SecureConnector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
        <constructor-arg ref="Server" />
                <constructor-arg>
                        <bean id="handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">
                                <property name="keyStorePath" value="${activemq.conf}/keystore.jks" />
                                <property name="keyStorePassword" value="password-3" />
                        </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
        <property name="port" value="8162" />
</bean>
...
```

**The question**

Should I use the same keystore generated with Let'sEncrypt for both SSL and HTTPS communication ? Or should I maintain them both separated for more (maybe?) security measures ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible to have a single certificate shared of course.,
But i usually give each server it's own certificate(client cert) I would recommend separate signed by same CA.

Comment: So, for each server I should generate a new certificate with Let'sEncript but then import all them into my new keystore/trustore. Is that right Jeryl ?

Comment: never tried "letsEcnrypt"(but looks cool!) , but i sure it means you have a single 'trustStoreKey and pass" from them.   you would use that same trustStore on both servers.  Then the  generated keystore cert(aka server cert) would be one on each server.